# How to properly set contents in a gitbook-plugin's block?

Tags: block, gitbook

#### Get the path of a file in gitbook head

This question touch the possibility to get a path of a specific file.

For example, to get some content, before page loads in a gitbook, is possible to add in "head:end" some customizations. This work fine when we need jquery loaded in `.

```
module.exports = {
   book: {
     ...
     /* Load files */
   html: {
     'head:end': function(current){
        console.log()
        var p = current.basePath+"/"+current.staticBase+"/plugins/myplugin/jquery-latest.min.js";
        ...
     }  
     ...
```

#### Get the path of a file in gitbook block

But in a custom block, how i do this?

```
blocks: {
    myblock: {
        process: function(current) {
          //current isnt same... :(
          // h
          console.log(current);
          var p = current.basePath+"/"+current.staticBase+"/plugins/myplugin/"+current.args[0];
```

Comment: According to http://toolchain.gitbook.com/plugins/api.html it seems that you can not. Why do you want to access it? Maybe there is another way to acheive your idea.